# Using `json:",string"` returning invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value

Tags: json, go

When trying to parse a json with a float value for distance to the following struct

```
type CreateBookingRequest struct {
    Distance          float64           `json:"distance,string"`
    DistanceSource    string            `json:"distanceSource"`
}
```

I get the following error

> json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted
>   value into [34 100 105 115 116 97 110 99 101 34]%!(EXTRA
>   *reflect.rtype=dto.CreateBookingRequest)

Is there a way for me to avoid the error/get a better error message?

**Edit:**
I am actually expecting the users of the API to pass in a string value but if they for some reason pass in a non-string value, I would like to be able to tell them clearly, instead of this hard to read error message.

Comment: Sounds like the JSON body you're decoding doesn't quote the distance field as a string. What is the JSON body you're trying to unmarshal?

Comment: @Matt I've updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 3):

I had to work with an API which sometimes quotes numbers and sometimes doesn't. The owners of the service weren't likely to fix it, so I came up with a simple workaround:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(":\s*)([\d\.]+)(\s*[,}])`)
rawJsonByteArray = re.ReplaceAll(rawJsonByteArray, []byte(`$1"$2"$3`))
```

Regular expressions are somewhat inefficient, but I don't believe I'd be able to implement something substantially faster.

Comment: I'd avoid the use of regexp. If I had to deal with such a JSON "type" I'd make my own Go type with [appropriate MarshalJSON and UnmarshalJSON methods](https://play.golang.org/p/KNPxDL1yqL) that used one of `bytes.Trim`, `bytes.TrimFunc`, or `data = data[1:len(data)-1]` depending on the exact needs.

Comment: @DaveC You should post that as an answer, it does exactly what is needed and is as idiomatic as it gets.

Comment: Except the original question doesn't need/want to accept both formats. They wanted just strings (with a readable user error otherwise).

Comment: That's correct, I've confused it with a similar thread in golang-nuts. Well, I'll post a self-answered question then :)

Answer (score 2):

[func unmarshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) state:

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object
>   keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its
>   tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive
>   match.

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

So, unmarshal expecting Distance should be `float64` by default. But as per tag, you are requesting unmarshal to except Distance as `string`. Here is data type missing matches.

So you have two options, either you change distance tag with [float64](http://play.golang.org/p/nrz41IS8pr) or marshal distance as [string](http://play.golang.org/p/JQ5p6FAxxx).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to deal with this issue is to use `json.Number`. It will parse all numeric data into `json.Number` type, which is a `string` alias. Then you have to cast it:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type x struct {
    Num json.Number `json:"price"`
}

func castToFloat64(num json.Number) (float64, error) {
    return num.Float64()
}

func main() {
    var resultHolder x
    data := `{"price":"5"}`
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &resultHolder)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
    }
    convertedNum, convertErr := castToFloat64(resultHolder.Num)
    if convertErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(convertErr)
    }
    fmt.Println(convertedNum*2, resultHolder.Num+"extraString")
}
```

[PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/TDnEA8j1nN5)

Comment: Николайчо, звънни, бате. (Аз съм Гошко.)

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the "distance" JSON value is encoded as a number instead of a string (per the "string" tag on the "Distance") field:

```
str := []byte(`{"distance":1.23,"distanceSource":"foo"}`)
// Note JSON number -------^
var cbr CreateBookingRequest
err := json.Unmarshal(str, &cbr)
// err => json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into [34 100 105 115 116 97 110 99 101 34]%!(EXTRA *reflect.rtype=main.CreateBookingRequest)
```

If you change the type of the distance value to a string (per the tag) then it works fine:

```
str := []byte(`{"distance":"1.23","distanceSource":"foo"}`)
// Note JSON string -------^
```

You could change the error message by identifying that specific error somehow and provide a different message.  You might also consider changing the tag for the Distance type to simply accept a number instead of a string:

```
type CreateBookingRequest struct {
  Distance       float64 `json:"distance"`
  ...
}

...
  str := []byte(`{"distance":1.23,"distanceSource":"foo"}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply saying you designated `Distance` as a string with your json annotations but in the json string you're trying to deserialize the value is not quoted (therefor not a string).

The solution is simple, either change this `json:"distance,string"` to `json:"distance"` or get json that matches your definition (meaning it has distince in quotes like `"Distance":"10.4"`)

Given, the error and the fact that your native Go type is a float64 I would advise getting rid of the string annotation.