# How to parse both plain and enquoted JSON numbers in Go?

Tags: json, go

I'm dealing with a third-party JSON-based API. Usually it wraps all numbers in quotes, but sometimes it doesn't. Nothing I can do about it.

I'm trying to come up with a solution, which parses the numbers regardless of whether they're enquoted or not. Standard library provides a `,string` field tag, which allows to map numeric fields to enquoted values, but, unfortunately, it then fails to process the value, if it's not in quotes.

```
func test(s string) {
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &struct {
    F1 float64
    F2 float64 `json:",string"`
  }{})
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  fmt.Println("success")
}

func main() {
  test(`{"f1": 1.23}`)   // success
  test(`{"f1": "1.23"}`) // cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type float64
  test(`{"f2": 1.23}`)   // invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into ...
  test(`{"f2": "1.23"}`) // success
}
```

[The Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/B-hYud9vcW)

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper solution is to "clone" float64 and define custom `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` for it:

```golang
type jsonFloat64 float64

func (f jsonFloat64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  return json.Marshal(float64(f))
}

func (f *jsonFloat64) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  if len(data) >= 2 && data[0] == '"' && data[len(data)-1] == '"' {
    data = data[1 : len(data)-1]
  }

  var tmp float64
  err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  *f = jsonFloat64(tmp)
  return nil
}
```

Then you'd be able to do something like this:

```golang
func test(s string) {
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &struct {
    F jsonFloat64
  }{})
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  fmt.Println("success")
}

func main() {
  test(`{"f": 1.23}`)   // success
  test(`{"f": "1.23"}`) // success
}
```

[The Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/czaVZuQYM4)

Feel free to adjust `UnmarshalJSON` to your needs, mine is pretty strict about the spacing. Credit goes to [Dave C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55504/dave-c), this was heavily inspired by [his comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213974/using-json-string-returning-invalid-use-of-string-struct-tag-trying-to-un/31595318#comment51144192_31595318) (which also features [more variations](https://play.golang.org/p/KNPxDL1yqL) on the solution above).

Alternatively, you could pre-process the JSON data with a regular expression, but don't do this if the solution above is a viable option, it's much faster.

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(":\s*)([\d\.]+)(\s*[,}])`)
rawJsonByteArray = re.ReplaceAll(rawJsonByteArray, []byte(`$1"$2"$3`))
```

Comment: Anyone curious about "adjust[ing] UnmarshalJSON to your needs" may want to see the [answer comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31595318/55504) and [playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/KNPxDL1yqL) that (I think) inspired this Q&A.

Comment: @DaveC Credited you in the answer. Pardon me for not doing so initially, don't know what I was thinking.